# @yield and @stack not working in laravel components

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I have an app with two main layouts *auth* and *app*.
The auth layouts is for my authentication views whiles the app layouts is for the main application views with sidebars and headers .
But they both share a the same css and js blocks.
So i decided to create two components (head.blade.php and scripts.blade.php) in a sub directory "includes" in the **resources/views/components** directory.
This is the content of my **includes/head.blade.php** file

```
@props(['title' => $title ?? ''])
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> {{ucfirst(config('app.name'))}} - {{ucfirst($title)}}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta content="Premium Multipurpose Admin & Dashboard Template" name="description" />
    <meta content="Themesbrand" name="author" />
    <!-- App favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{asset('assets/images/favicon.ico')}}">

    <!-- Bootstrap Css -->
    <link href="{{asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" id="bootstrap-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Icons Css -->
    <link href="{{asset('assets/css/icons.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- App Css-->
    <link href="{{asset('assets/css/app.min.css')}}" id="app-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Custom Css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
    <!-- Page Css-->
   @stack('page-css')

</head>
```

And this is the content of my **includes/scripts.blade.php** file.

```
<!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
<script src="{{asset('assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/libs/metismenu/metisMenu.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/libs/simplebar/simplebar.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/libs/node-waves/waves.min.js')}}"></script>

<!-- App js -->
<script src="{{asset('assets/js/app.js')}}"></script>
<!-- Page js -->
@stack('page-js')
```

This is how i call each of them in my app layout file.

```
This is for the css

<x-includes.head :title="$title" />

@push('page-css')
    <!-- Custom Css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
@endpush


This one for the js

<x-includes.scripts />
@push('page-js')
    <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
@endpush
```

But is not working.
**SUMMARY**: What am trying to achieve is that, i want to able to use those components in each of my layouts. But i also want to be able inject custom page css and js to pages that have custom css and js files. The components works fine but the @stack and @push are not working. I also used @yield and @section and i didn't get any result.
I want to know if am doing it right and also if there is another way to achieve this.

Comment: Are you @include('scripts') and @include('head') somewhere?

Comment: I have use include derivative before, but this time, instead of include, am using anonymous components and i want to dynamically inject css and js links to them using **@stack** or **@yield**  I don't know why is not working.

Comment: You will still need to do something to get the 'scripts' and 'head' files included into the layout.

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper if you read the question, i said they are blade components so i was able to get them inside the layout and it worked fine. But the *@stack* or *@yield* derivatives inside those components are not working. Because when i use *@push* or *@section* to inject my scripts or css, they don't get injected.